# Navigation controller can not push view controller in iOS 7 when project using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

Now in my project I have an issue with auto layout.

In iOS 8: It's still working well.

However in iOS 7: It pushed to view and can not load content the view. In navigation I saw it changed title. I guess auto layout is the cause of the error.

Code:

```
MyViewController * viewcontroller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

[employeeListVC.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:employeeListVC animated:YES];
```

Please help me to resolve it. Many thanks.

Comment: check if your controller is embedded in navigation controller or not.

Comment: I checked navigation controller. It was not nil

Answer (score 1):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
MyViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess auto layout is not the cause. One possible case is that the `MyViewController` is not embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Check `self.navigationController` is `nil` or not.

Error message from console will be helpful (if exists).

Comment: It doesn't error, It just can not load the content of view.
`self.navigationController` is not `nil`
This is show log `po self.navigationController
<UINavigationController: 0x7fcd5f61bf80>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Segue instead of Navigation Controller. That better one as per my personal opinion.

Steps: 
1. Embed your viewcontrollers [Initial View Controller must be embed in Navigation Controller]

2. Give a name identifier your segue.
3. Write code in your event

   `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueBlockedContacts" sender:self];`
4. Implement prepareForSegue method.

   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   ```
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueBlockedContacts"]) {

       BlockedContactTableVC *blockedContactVC = segue.destinationViewController;
       [blockedContactVC.blockedContacts removeAllObjects];
       blockedContactVC.blockedContacts = blockedContacts;
       blockedContactVC.myDelegate = self;
   }
   ```

   }

Thats it.

Comment: I tested on log frame of the view controller and I saw it still working normal, navigation right, frame of view is right. However, the content view can that consists of table view does not show.